# Aligning profiles between an enterprise environment and a developer one

Tags: profile, production

I am trying to align 2 profiles, referring to my enterprise environment. 
In my starting environment,  I have Read, Edit and Delete, in my Profile X, for Account object.

When I try to modify the profile X, in the developer environment, or a.k.a Production, I see that I can't choose other permission, other than Read.

I notice that the profile that I want to align, is already created/cloned. My task was to check if the profiles are aligned, but I found this profile obstacle.

Please, anyone, has any idea, what could have happened.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
Endrit.

Comment: Is the profile that you can't choose other permission other than Read, a Salesforce Standard profile? One way to find out is to clone that profile and then see if you still can`t assign other permissions.

Comment: Actually, It's a custom progfile. I was considering to clone a new std profile, so I could choose other rights than Read, but this is not a resilient solution. I want to know why this happens too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Profile Compare](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/profile-comparator-for-sa/ijbipklcimjilmnaffocmjkfddhpaadghttps://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/profile-comparator-for-sa/ijbipklcimjilmnaffocmjkfddhpaadg?hl=en-US) Chrome extension let's you easily compare profiles from the same or different orgs.

You could also export your profiles using the Force.com IDE, and then manually compare the two in excel, by having each profile in a column, and adding a third with the formula

```
IF(B2=C2, True, False)
```